# Index / Match formula with multiple IDs and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please see picture:
I am trying to match some text in column B with some text in column V based on the IDs. So for example, for ID 26 in column A, I want to say that 'Escalation & follow up' matches Communications in Column V. However, each ID can have multiple values so my index / match formula is not properly working.

This is the formula I used:

```
=IF((INDEX(V:V;MATCH([@ID];U:U;0))="Communications") * ([@[Manual Theme]]="Escalation & follow up");TRUE;FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula - if you have Excel365:

It checks by using `FILTER`-function if there is an entry in table2 for according ID and Automatic = "Communications"

```
=IF((ROWS(FILTER(Table2[ID],(Table2[ID]=[@ID])*(Table2[Automatic]="Communications"),0)>0)*([@[Manual Theme]]="Escalation & follow up")),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with <kbd>FILTER( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=SUM((FILTER(Table4[Automatic],Table4[ID]=[@ID],"")="Communications")*([@[Manual Theme]]="Escalation & follow up"))>0
```

---